# MySQL DB: performance and partitioning

Tags: mysql, performance, database-partitioning

I've migrate an access DB to a MySQL DB. In particular, in this DB I've a table with almost 5 million of rows. The most part of operations on this table are queries (filters to select a data subset).

I'm interested in performance. The partitioning of the MySQL DB could enhance the performance? In this case, what type of partitioning is the better to use?

**EDIT**

The "data filter" most used will be, I think, the date. But normally more criteria will be used.

Comment: you don't need to partition a table with only 5 millions of rows; just provide proper indexes and make sure MySQL is setup to use enough RAM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is too generic.

Yes, MySQL partitioning can enhance performance - that's its purpose.
MySQL partitioning works well, when you have clear rules about the subset of data you are accessing more often.

For example if you have a timestamp column, and you're usually querying the data for the past year, you could devise a partitioning scheme to improve performance.

Please supply more details about your table, if you wish to receive a better answer.